# Full house vs Full house weak

Tags: full-house

how can i lost with a A2 vs 68 full house? i dont know  [image]

Comment: your full house is 22266, and it is worse than his full house 66622.

Answer (score 0):

Your full-house has **three deuces** and two aces.
His full-house has **three sixes** and two deuces.

Since sixes are more valuable than deuces, you lose the hand